# Write a program in python that in a loop asks the user for a integer until the user prints out 0

Tags: python, loops, integer, user-input

Im studying for a exam in python and I dont know what to do with this freaking question.
Write a program in python that in a loop asks the user for a integer until the user prints out 0. After the user prints out 0 the program shall print out the mean value of this program.

Pardon my probably not so well written English.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Josh Damn, you beat me by 2 seconds

Answer (score 5):

```
from __future__ import division
data = [int(i) for i in iter(raw_input, '0')]
print "mean:", sum(data) / len(data)
```

Comment: We shouldn't really be doing people's homework for them. But +1 for the `iter(callable, sentinel)` construct - didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to really read through Python.org's WIKI.  It's a great source of information and [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) will surely get you on your way.

Comment: Ha, thanks a lot for that link. I've never come across that website.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x = []
i = ''
while i != 0:
    i = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
    x.append(i)

sum = 0
for number in x:
    sum = sum + int(number)

print float(sum/int(len(x)-1))
```